# How would I create an "About" page like this for my app? How do I have a UITableView (grouped) under a UIView?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Take this about page for Things:

[image]

I'm having trouble creating something similar. I just want a UITableView under a UIView with a UIImageView and a UILabel in it.

If I use a UIViewController and so I can position the UITableView downward, I get this error: "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances."

If I use a UITableViewController with a grouped style and use `contentInset` on `self.tableView` to move it down (`[self.tableView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(150,0,0,0)];`) I can't figure out how to place a view above it. If I try to attach anything to `self.view` it crashes (obviously). Same happens if I attach anything to `self.tableView`.

I then tried making the UIView the header of my UITableView section (I only need one section) but I can't get it to move up enough. It just sits inside the UITableView almost.

How do I have a UITableView (grouped style) exist with a UIView above it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved easily using the `tableHeaderView` property of `UITableView`. If you are using Interface Builder (which it looks like you are), then you can just drag a `UIView` above the table view and it will be set as the table's header view. All you need is a `UITableViewController`; no need for `UIViewController` and manually laying it out.

Comment: Can't ask for easier than that.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the view probably isn't placed on top of the table but rather within the table's section 0 header. Or, even more likely, the view in question is just a regular UITableViewCell with a 0 alpha background.

Either of these options would allow the top view to be scrolled out of frame as the user scrolls under every condition.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [MDAboutController] (https://github.com/mochidev/MDAboutController)

It's easy to integrate and you don't have to waste any time configuring the UITableView.